# pseudocode with FOR

Tags: pseudocode

```
for j = n − 1 to 1 step − 1 do
```

does this means for all j in [1 .. n-1] or [2 .. n-1] ?

Comment: In C-like languages:
`for (int j = n - 1; j != 1; j--)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for j = n − 1 to 1 step − 1 do` is a countdown.

It will start at j and count down to 1 (inclusive).

So if j is 6, then it will go down 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

***twist:*** Now if your j is a negative value, then you should consider that it will go upto the min negative first, then rollover to the max positive and then count down to 1.

Comment: Umm, don't you mean "if n is 6"? Also, most languages would do a loop where the range doesn't overlap as not doing any loops at all, not as going clear around number space until it wraps and hits the ending value from the other side.

Comment: i was looking for the inclusive (or not) word. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If n=5 then the for loop is executed 4 times with J equal to 4 then 3, then 2, and finally 1 in that order

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear to me. That means it counts down from n-1 to 1.